# How do I safely pass API keys to a React Front end that is needed for a React Component

Tags: reactjs, api, express, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I am using @react-google-maps/api to create a map component on React. In order to load the component we need to pass an API key to useJsApiLoader. How do I handle securing the API key so it is not visible on the front end in this situation? (I have a express.js back end)

Here is the documentation for @react-google-maps https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

Create a .env file in the root directory of the project and add the variables in that file. Import the variables using react-dotenv package. Hope this helps

[Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dotenv)

Comment: Try to give it more context so that the user does not have to go elsewhere to look for the answer or try to understand what you are trying to convey. Let the link you linked be more of a support.